# Avoid MS Access SQL insert bug

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I am converting an Access ADP file to ACCDB in preparation for Access 2016.

It's currently Access 2013 while all the functional testing is done before we move that to Access 2016 for compatibility testing.

I have one form where inserting a new record displays `#Deleted` after the insert.

I have traced through the profiler that it does 2 `sp_executesql` calls

One does the insert

The second queries for the new identity column value by using all the column values.

Unfortunately, there are several column values that are `NULL`, and the text shows it is querying for `Field = @P6` (where `@P6 = NULL`) rather than `Field IS NULL`.

I've checked, and replacing the `NULL` variable checks with `IS NULL` does return the correct key value.

Is there a known bug relating to this?
I'm assuming it would be either in Access or ODBC

If so, can someone point me to the appropriate documentation so I can arrange any required upgrades, etc.

ODBC Connection I am using:

`ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};APP=TEST;SERVER=TEST_SQL;DATABASE=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;TABLE=dbo.Inspection`

Comment: You need to be a little more specific. Are you just doing a normal insert in the form? If so, where is that `sp_executesql` call coming from (are there triggers on the table)? An easy fix might be turning the _Fetch Defaults_ property on the form to _No_, but that has consequences for functionality.

Comment: It's not really a bug, in SQL nothing actually '= Null' . In fact Null does not equal Null as far as SQL is concerned. 'Is Null'  or 'Not Is Null' is the only way to check for a null value directly.

Comment: Please add the definition of your Sql Server table to the question. There may be data types that Access / ODBC doesn't handle well. Or you may need a newer driver than the ancient `{SQL Server}`, that would be `{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}` -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files

Comment: Are you doing this insert via code, or just letting the form do the insert? (the normal approach is no code, and let the form do the update/insert for you). In "most" cases, this error tends to occur if you have bit columns, and you have NOT set the default bit column to have a default of (0) for its default value.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal It's Access doing it, and the columns in question are varchar, and int that are being passed as null.

Comment: @Andre  That though had occurred to me after I posted.  I generate the connection based on the installed drivers, and assumed one of the Native Client drivers was being used.  Unfortunately, my "test" environment for this is their terminal server, and on top of that, Server 2016 commissioning starts in 2 weeks.  I'll talk to the network support engineer and see if I can get a newer version installed.

Comment: @?Minty, it's not a bug in SQL, it's a bug in (I assume) either Access or the ODBC driver that's generating the dynamic SQL it uses.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth That's the call generated (by Access or the ODBC driver) for the insert when I run the SQL Profiler

Comment: As I stated, you need to check for null bit columns. Your tables all need a PK, and you should also add a timestamp column to each table. Null bit fields is the most common reason for what you see. Adding a rowversion column also helps. So ensure a PK, and ensure any bit column has a default set to (0) to prevent this issue.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal There is a PK, it is the retrieval of the PK that is returning 0 lines due to the X = NULL evaluation.  I already tried with a timestamp, no effect, and I wouldn't expect it to for this scenario as it's an insert then select, so no prior timestamp value to reference.  All the bit columns in the table have a value set from the UI, it is only varchar and int columns that are being passed as null in the queries.

Comment: Did not say or suggest to set bit defaults on the client side - you have to set the default to 0 on the server side table desinger. And all tables should have that row version column. (column type timestamp). And after you add the defaults for the  bit columns and the timestamp column, you have to re-link the access table(s). And yes, the timestamp helps even in this case, since Access will "check/use" the time stamp column to see if changes to record have occurred - including when having just done a insert.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal  Yeap, tried all that, made no difference.  Access does NOT do a timestamp reference back to SQL on an insert though.

Comment: then edit  your post - include the table create statement in sql. And everyone here can create the table, link to it, and see if it fails.